# Java:Why can't we override a method to make it static?

Tags: java, static

Why can't we override a non-static method to make it static. I got this error when trying to do it :

> This static method cannot hide the instance method from aSuperClass.

Many thanks!

Comment: Which language C# JAVA ????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2831429/516167

Comment: sorry , I didn't mention, JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods are not overridden in the way Polymorphism works. However when you try to override a static method Java allows the concept of Name Hiding.

Now coming to your question. A Static method can be invoked both by Class Name and Object name. If you override a non static method with a static one how will the compiler know which one to invoke.

```
static void f(){}

A obj = new A();
```

`A.f()` and `obj.f()` will both invoke the static method. If you put a Non-Static `f()` here the confusion starts for `obj.f()`.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding means providing a new implementation in the child class for **instance method**, Instance method may or may not work with the class instance members. Its not logical to override them and redefine them as `static`. `static` means the method is related to the class, not to the instance of the class.

You can't do that in C# as well as Java.

For C# Look at [override - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx)

> You cannot use the new, static, or virtual modifiers to modify an
>   override method.