# Static method overriding in Java

Tags: java

```
class B extends A {
    static public void printMe(){
        System.out.println("in static B");
    }
}
class A{
    static public void printMe(){
        System.out.println("In static A");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.printMe();
    }
```

Why is the output "In static A" ?

Comment: There is no "Static method overriding in Java"

Comment: @Eran if you have issue with the title I changed it.

Comment: Consequence: don't use static: use a singleton if you need only one instance (of course the singleton implementation may use static inside)

Comment: Related / duplicate: [Is it possible to override a static method in derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2831426)

Comment: There is a reason why you should never call a static method on an "object instance" - you should just say `A.printMe()` or `B.printMe()`. I consider Java allowing to call static methods on an instance an error in the language specs...

Comment: I have no issue with the title. I just stated that there's no such thing in Java, which is why you see the described behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static members bind to type rather than implemented type. Hence you see the methods executing from class A.

And static members are not to be ovverriden and they share same copy     regardless of instance state.

If you need methods to be ovveriden, do not use them as static members.

Comment: "static members are not to be overridden". They can't be overridden. They can be 'hidden' by a new static implementation in the child class, though.

Comment: True. Stressing only about overriding.

Comment: I understand, but sometimes people assume that if you can put a static method with the same signature in a child class, it means it has been overridden. Causes quite a lot of mistakes

Answer (score 0):

**Static member or method** belongs to class level instead of specific instance.

A *static class* will have only 1 instance even if you create multiple instance or do not create instance.

In your case, since you have created instance of class A, method inside class A is implemented.

Another way to get a clear concise for the problem scenario is try running the code mentioned below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
A.printMe();
}
```

You will get clear idea.

Comment: the point is: the instance is of B, it's the declaration that limits it to an A.