# Static initializer not invoked for a derived class

Tags: java

The following Java code does not invoke the static initializer of class `B`. Why?

Code:

```
class A 
{
    static 
    {
        System.out.println("A static init");
    }

    public static void f() 
    {
        System.out.println("f() called");
    }
}

class B extends A 
{
    static 
    {
        System.out.println("B static init");
    }
}

public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
        B.f(); //invokestatic  #16                 // Method com/db/test/B.f:()V
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
A static init
f() called
```

Tested on JDK 1.8.0_25

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475172/java-static-initialization-with-inheritance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no such thing as "static constructor". It's a static initialization block, and it is only executed when the class is initialized. Since you are calling a static method of class A (even though you are referring to it via class B), there is no need to initialize class B. Calling `B.f();` is the same as calling `A.f();`.

The static initialization block of class B will be executed if you create an instance of class B or access a static member/method of class B.

Here are the **only** conditions that trigger class initialization ([JLS 12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)):

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> ```
>  T is a class and an instance of T is created.
>
>  T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.
>
>  A static field declared by T is assigned.
>
>  A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).
>
>  T is a top level class (§7.6), and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.
> ```

Comment: Addition: what happend if class B overrides f() ?

Comment: @Niels, there's no such thing as overriding on `static` methods. If there is a `static` method `f()` in `B`, then it will be called.

Comment: @Niels You can't override a static method. If B would define its own static `f()` method, class B would be loaded and its static initialization block would be executed, and that `f()` method is the method that would be executed. In such case, A would also be loaded, since it's a super-class of B.

Comment: Would it be possible to call this static initializer?

Comment: @Thomas The static initializer is called automatically. You can't call it explicitly.

Comment: How about this one: Class.forName(MyClass.class.getName())
Isn't this a proper way to make sure the initializer is called?

Answer (score 5):

Since only class `A` defines the method `f(`), class `B` is *loaded* but not *initialized*.

You could use `java -verbose:class MyClassName` to check this.

On a jdk6 / jdk 8 machine, this will be printed.

```
[Loaded App from file:/C:/XXXX/]
[Loaded A from file:/C:/XXXXXX]
[Loaded B from file://C:/XXXXXXX]
A static init
f() called
```

Class `B` will be initialized *lazily* but loaded *greedily* (since it is being referred).

Change your code to `A.f()`. Then you will see that `B` is not loaded.

```
[Loaded App from file:/C:/XXXX/]
[Loaded A from file:/C:/XXXXX]
A static init
f() called
```

Note : Class *loading* and *initialization* are 2 different things. Check documentation for `Class.forName()` for details.

Comment: Do you know if B is guaranteed to get loaded, or could it be platform dependent?

Comment: @pbabcdefp  - It will be VM (implementation) dependent. Some implementations will load `B` greedily, others might resolve the call to `A` directly thus not loading `B`.