# Getting Null Pointer after having field initialized in Test class inside static block

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, initialization, testng

Here is my class

```
package com.myCompany.test;

// imports

@Test
public class Test{
    private static final Map<Type, String> depMap;
    static {
        depMap = new HashMap<>();
        depMap.put(Type.ONE, "1234");
    }

    @Test(groups="small")
    public void testOne(){
        // something
        String typeOneVal = depMap.get(Type.ONE); // NullPointerException
        // assertions
    }
}
```

The test suite looks like below:

```
<test name="Small Test Set">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <exclude name="brokenTests" />
            <include name="small" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    
    <packages>
        <package name="com.myCompany.test.*" />
    </packages>
</test>
```

How can `depMap` ever be `null` when this TestNG class is executed by method, class, suite etc? It runs on my local fine **but fails in CI job**, both executing the test suite. Pretty confused now!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing the static block to an `@BeforeClass` method. This will ensure that it works using the tools provided by the testing framework.

```
@BeforeClass
public void init() {
    depMap = new HashMap<>();
    depMap.put(Type.ONE, "1234");
}
```

This seems similar in terms of the core issue of the static initializer:
[Static initializer doesn't run during JUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914409/static-initializer-doesnt-run-during-junit-tests)

Testing frameworks sometimes use reflection and other tools to optimize unit test execution which can cause errors like you're seeing. Without knowing more about your toolchain it is tough to say exactly what would cause the issue.

Comment: Thanks Joe, but it wont work when I run it via Suite without <class> tag.

Comment: Which <class> tag are you referring to? Did the annotation not work for you?

Comment: No. If I give <class> in the suite xml, only then it will work. `@BeforeMethod` works with <method> tag, `@BeforeTest` works with <test> tag. If you try, you will get NPE.

Comment: Just add BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true) . It will work with xml provided in question.

Comment: Yes, I did that only at the end. But how does above fails?!