# Finding extender from abstract class in static method

Tags: java, reflection, static, extend, superclass

I have a set of basic classes,
ei:

`public class Item{
}`

I want to add feature to extend basic class with Storable ability:

1. new parameter to keep data from storage in an object
2. new static method to load objects from storage

I created an abstract class Storable:

```
public abstract class Storable{
    private StorageRow str;

    public void setStorageRow(StorageRow row){
        str = row;
    }

    public static ArrayList<? extends Storable> getAll(){
        ArrayList<Storable> ans = new ArrayList<Storable>();
        Class<Storable> extenderClass = ??????


        ArrayList<StorageRow> rows = Storage.get(llallala);
        for(StorageRow row : rows){
            Object extender = extenderClass.newInstance();
            // Now with reflection call to setStorageRow(row);
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Now I extend my basic class with Storable:

`public class Item extends Storable{}`

The call is:

```
ArrayList<Item> items = (ArrayList<Item>) Item.getAll();
```

The main question is: Now I'm inside static method getAll of superclass. How to get a subclass?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to do, but the short answer is you probably can't.  But you could probably add an `Item.getAll()` method which used `Storable.getItem()`.

Comment: if you want your load method to behave polymorphically you can't make it static.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Static methods belong to the class where you declared it, not to its children ([they're not inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740528/inheritance-vs-static-in-java)). So if you want to know from where it was called, you need to pass the class as argument to it.

```
public static ArrayList<? extends Storable> getAll(Class<? extends Storable>)
```

Another more cumbersome way to do it is to get the stack trace and check which class did the call, but I don't think this kind of hack is worth it when an argument suffices.

**EDIT**: example using the stacktrace:

```
class AnotherClass {

    public AnotherClass() {
        Main.oneStaticMethod();
    }
}

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws OperationNotSupportedException
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new AnotherClass();
    }

    public static void oneStaticMethod() {
        final StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread()
                .getStackTrace();
        final String callingClassName = trace[2].getClassName();
        try {
            final Class<?> callingClass = Class.forName(callingClassName);
            System.out.println(callingClass.getCanonicalName());
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is the easy way and it will sure work.
The disadvantage is that the code looks ugly: Item.getAll(Item.class)

The trick with stack didn't work to me, 'cause I see superclass in stack, not subclass

Comment: I've added an example on how to get the class calling a static method using the stacktrace. Best idea for this would be to create a static `Class<?> getCallingClass()` method and use it whenever necessary. I still think first way is better because it's simpler, more maintainable, more readable...